# codeigniter header template load model function

Tags: codeigniter, templates, foreach, view

I'm passing $data into a view on each page and have an autoload in place. Before the view I have the following:

```
$data['category'] = $this->productModel->listCategories();
```

I'm trying to find a way where I don't have to have this on each page view controller. I've tried placing the code inside the header.php template but I get undefined variable category.

Inside the header template I have:

```
<?php foreach ($category as $cat) : ?>
          <li><a href="/products/<?php echo url_title($cat->ProductCategory, '-', TRUE); ?>"><?php echo $cat->ProductCategory; ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Totally stumped!

I need it to run on every page as it's in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in constructor of the controller and reference it in any view the function inside same controller loads.

$query_result= $this->productModel->listCategories();

Assign the query result to a global variable and simply use $this->load->vars($query_result) in the any view of the controller in which you are working.